# A* algorithm on unity cant deploy more unit

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, a-star

Hello I need help on my project , i want to make game like " Dead Ahead Zombie Warfare "

now i want to implement A* algorithm on the pathfinding on every unit in the game , and i follow the tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn1XRIaROM4

when i deploy one unit to follow moving object , no problem. But.. 
when i want to deploy 2 unit on same script , and follow a moving object its like stuck on each other

please help me , Thanks.

this is the script for follow the path when path is found :

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Transform target;
float speed = 5;
Vector3[] path;
int targetIndex;
public Image healtbar;
int darah=100;
void Start() {

}
public void kenaserang(int jum)
{
    darah -= jum;
    healtbar.fillAmount = darah/100f;

}
void carimusuhterdekat(){
    float jarakterpendek = Mathf.Infinity;
    musuh musuhterdekat = null;
    musuh[] semuamusuh = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<musuh>();

    foreach (var musuhsekarang in semuamusuh)
    {
        float jarakmusuh=(musuhsekarang.transform.position-this.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (jarakmusuh<jarakterpendek)
        {
            jarakterpendek = jarakmusuh;
            musuhterdekat = musuhsekarang;
            target = musuhterdekat.transform;
        }
    }


}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    carimusuhterdekat();
    PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathFound);

}


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "musuh")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

    }
}
public void OnPathFound(Vector3[] newPath, bool pathSuccessful)
{
    if (pathSuccessful)
    {
        path = newPath;
        targetIndex = 0;
        StopCoroutine("FollowPath");
        StartCoroutine("FollowPath");

    }
}
IEnumerator FollowPath() {
    Vector3 currentWaypoint = path[0];
    while (true) {
        if (transform.position == currentWaypoint) {
            targetIndex ++;
            if (targetIndex >= path.Length) {
                yield break;
            }
            currentWaypoint = path[targetIndex];
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,currentWaypoint,speed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;

    }
}

public void OnDrawGizmos() {
    if (path != null) {
        for (int i = targetIndex; i < path.Length; i ++) {
            Gizmos.color = Color.black;
            Gizmos.DrawCube(path[i], Vector3.one);

            if (i == targetIndex) {
                Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, path[i]);
            }
            else {
                Gizmos.DrawLine(path[i-1],path[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[this is when i only deploy 1 unit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS98S.png)

[this is when i deploy 2 or more unit , it don't follow the unit well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK50c.png)

Comment: "and follow a moving object its like stuck on each other" - you mean you want two objects to appear as one?

Comment: when one unit follow the path to one still target , it has no problem. when one unit follow the path to one moving object it has no problem . but when 2 unit follow on one moving object , it cant move.